# AJAX Wordpress ACF update with button click id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

> I using ACF wordpress to update acf field for user to populate with button id click. 
>   I am getting Error as admin-ajax.php with 400
>   **Error POST https://domainname/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 ()**
>
> **Wordpress code on template**

```
<button class="get_project" id="1479" name="urbtnid" data-postid="147">Get project</button>
<button class="get_userbtn" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>" id="get_userbtn" ><?php echo get_current_user_id() ?></button>
```

**

> **JQUery AJAX Code**

**

```
  jQuery(function($){
    $('.get_project').click(function() {
      var stdid = jQuery('#get_userbtn').attr('value');
      var stdbtnid = this.id;
       jQuery.ajax({
             url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
             data: dataString,
            success : function( response ) {
                 console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })

});
```

**

> **Function.php code**

**

```
function my_enqueue_ajax_save() {

    wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pradeep-js-css/my-ajax-id-save-script.js', array('jquery') , false, true );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_ajax_save' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' ); 

function my_action(){
    $postid = $_POST['stdid1'];;
    $fieldname = 'last_question_viewed'; 
    $fieldvalue = $_POST['stdbtnid1'];          
    update_post_meta($postid, $fieldname, $fieldvalue);
    echo $postid;
    wp_die($fieldname = '', $fieldvalue = '', $postid = ''); 

}
```

> **Updated jquery with action**

```
jQuery(function($){

      var stdid = jQuery('#get_userbtn').attr('value');
      var stdbtnid = this.id;
      var dataString = 'stdid1=' + stdid + '&stdbtnid1=' + stdbtnid; 
      $('.get_project').click(function() {
       var data = {
      action: "my_action",
      stdid: stdid,
      stdbtnid1: stdbtnid
    };
       jQuery.ajax({
             url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type : 'post',
             data: data,
            success : function( response ) {
                 console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: Where are you specifying which action hook to hit in your AJAX call? Usually you send that along in the `data` object as `action: 'action_name`

Comment: I Have updated the code as with action but still getting same error.. I wish i have done correct

Comment: Added the action with jquery

Comment: Can Anyone Please help????

I am trying very hard to make it work

Comment: Probably no one can

Comment: Please suggest and Solution